# How can I do this mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all `http://localhost/webportal/organizations/32` requests to `http://localhost/webportal/organizations/32?qt-organization_tabs=tab1#qt-organization_tabs` (where 32 is a variable).

How can I do this using mod_rewite?

**Update:**

I have updated the URLs above, the URLs originally posted were not correct, anyway I tried the following rule and it is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/organizations/(.+)$ ^/organizations/$1?qt-organization_tabs=tab1#qt-organization_tabs [L,R]
```

All the other rules are working properly, here is the relevant part of my htaccess file (Drupal CMS):

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
  RewriteBase /webportal
  RewriteRule ^/organizations/(.+)$ ^/organizations/$1?qt-organization_tabs=tab1#qt-organization_tabs [L,R]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?webportal/organizations/(.+)$ /pepris/webportal/$1?qt-organization_tabs=tab1#qt-organization_tabs [L,R]
```

You can also use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch ^/?webportal/organizations/(.+)$ /pepris/webportal/$1?qt-organization_tabs=tab1#qt-organization_tabs
```